# AJAX response caching / onclick-event inside of a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, caching

I´m using AJAX to execute some server-side actions and refresh a table inside the page without reloading the page itself. All works fine at first view. But I wrote a function in PHP to send an email and execute it via AJAX. When I´m starting this action for a second time old responses gets triggered.

*What exactly happens:*

- I´m clicking a Button to execute the "Sendmail-Action"
- a Modal asks me if I want to execute the action and I´m clicking yes
- a PHP-Script gets executed and sends the email
- the Modal gets closed after the PHP-Script finishes (~2s)
- the table (with emails and so on) gets refreshed and the status updated

*What happens next:*

- I´m clicking a Button to execute the "Sendmail-Action" for the same
  or another entry in my table
- a Modal asks me if I want to execute the action and I´m clicking yes
- the Event triggers twice / 4xAjax-Request instead of 2 (I can see it in my Chrome-Console)
- the Modal closes and 2 Mails sended

*What I´ve tried to get rid of this behaviour:*

- checked my JS with JSHint
- checked my PHP-Code (no errors in apache error.log)
- redesigned the PHP-Script (Sendmail), now the AJAX executes a function
- tried different browsers
- deactivated AJAX-Caching
- completely deactivated Caching with Apache (correct Headers)
- deactivated Session-Caching in my php.ini (I don´t use sessions)
- unset all variables in PHP
- cleared the cache for all of my browsers
- checked all headers
- searched several hours for solutions

*More information about my setup:*

- jQuery 2.1.4
- php 5.4
- Apache 2.2

I can´t find a solution to my problem and maybe this is caused because I´m adding the content dynamically to the table. I had the same problem in the past and I´m thinking the Modal (which is also dynamic) triggers the click on the "Yes-Button" twice.

Comment: How do you bind the click event to send emails? If you have done this in a function then every time you call that function it will register a new event and doubles it.

Comment: @Jai I´m executing the action inside document ready like this to open the modal  (shortened) `$(document).on('click', '.email-resend, .email-send, .show-doc, .show-acc, .more-acc, .no, .yes, .termin', function(){$.fn.doAction(classname, comEntry);});` and then in the function something like this `$(document).on('click', '.bt-ok', function(){$.ajax({`. How can I delete an old event for that function then?

Comment: Hmm i guessed it right...! You can put that outside of that function. where you have ajax call.

Comment: Sounds good. I´ll try your suggestion and come back if it works (or not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put your ajax click handler outside of that function:

```
$(document).on('click', '.email-resend, .email-send, .show-doc, .show-acc, .more-acc, .no, .yes, .termin', function(){
    $.fn.doAction(classname, comEntry);
});
```

---

As you mentioned that you have placed this in the function. Instead you should put this outside of it:

```
$(document).on('click', '.bt-ok', function(){
   $.ajax({
     ....
   });
});
```

**Edit by @pandora:** Or just use a second function (in my case) like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.bt-ok', function(){
    $.fn.sendRequest($('#modal').attr('data-1'), $('#modal').attr('data-2'));
});
```

Then I can call the function like this and execute the AJAX:

```
$.fn.sendRequest = function(data1, data2) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'target.php',
        cache: false,
        data: { gimme1 : data1, gimme2 : data2 },
        success: function(response) {
            // Show Error
            if(response.length > 0){
                alert(response);
            }

            // Reload Content
            $.fn.Reload('','');

            // Close Modal
            $('#modal').css({'display' : 'none'});
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Extended your answer with my example and hope this helps everyone having the same problem.